# Determine which dependency is being used in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I am working with a large, complex project written by other people and need to find out which dependencies are being used.

The main issue is that there is a "Referenced Libraries" folder in the project structure pane, and an old version of a library is listed there.

However, there is another folder called "Maven Dependencies" and in that folder the up to date libary is listed.

How can I determine which library is being loaded when I run the project from the IDE?

Eclipse Version:  Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)

Comment: The question is also why do you have that dependency in double to begin with... Possibly because it was added manually through Eclipse. Refresh the Maven project (Alt + F5, click update) and see if it's still there. Another possibility is that the `.classpath` was created with e.g. `mvn eclipse:eclipse` at the beginning and now it is messed up with M2E. The bottom-line is that even if you can know which library is going to be used _within Eclipse_, it is very fragile and it very probably will not work when you package the app with Maven and run it standalone (outside of Eclipse) afterwards.

Comment: @Tunaki Nevertheless, I do want to understand which is being used in the IDE environment. We have a bug that could possibly be caused by the previous version of the lib. For various reasons, we cannot test the maven build standalone. So, I need to know when I am running and encountering that bug, which version of the library is active.

Comment: In Which version of Eclipse IDE ?

Comment: @SrikanthA  Neon.1a Release (4.6.1) I have updated the question